# Code::Blocks - how to compile multiple source files

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I'm trying to compile a program with multiple source files - two CPP files and a header file, with code::blocks. As an example, I have created the following three files (an example program created by someone else on another forum):

main.cpp:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "other.h"

int main (void)
{
    printf("%d\n", getfavoritenumber());

    return 0;
}
```

other.cpp

```
#include "other.h"

int getfavoritenumber(void)
{
    return 3;
}
```

other.h

```
#ifndef _OTHER_H_
#define _OTHER_H_

int getfavoritenumber(void);

#endif
```

Despite the fact that these three files *should* link to each other, I receive the error "Linking stage skipped (build target has no object files to link)" when I try to build the project.

What am I doing wrong? Trying to compile the individual files presents the error "That file isn't assigned to any target".

Comment: What type of project do you have selected?  You should be selecting "console application."

Answer (score 22):

Here is what worked for me:

Go to the left panel that says projects, and right-click on .cpp file. Select properties, then go to build. Check the boxes under the heading Belongs in Targets:  "Debug" and "Release"

Answer (score 1):

I did this:

- I created a **Console Project** in **Code::Blocks**
- For each file i did `File|New` to create an empty file, added it to the project with the names you specified and pasted the relevant code from  your question into each file.
- Compiled and ran the resulting executable.

Everything worked as expected. If it doesn't work for you, please describe how you are creating the project. Code::Blocks absolutely needs a project - it doesn't work  well with individual files. If you want that, use GCC from the command line.

**Edit:**

- It is generally a good idea to install the compiler separately from CB, which is really only an IDE. I am assuming we are on Windows here. Go to http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net  and download the latest GCC compiler from there. Check it works from the command line.
- Then in CB go to `Settings|Compiler and Debugger` and select the `Toolchains executables` tab. Then navigate to the root of the directory where you installed the TDM GCC stuff (the root, not the bin directory within the root), and all should be well.

And if at the end of the day this doesn't work, try the CB support forums at http://forums.codeblocks.org.

Comment: I am creating the project exactly as described. I have alse tried jonsca's suggestion of using the 'Console Application' project type. I am using the default compiler - GNU GCC compiler. This might be the problem - there are several compilers to choose from. How do I know if they are properly installed? (I presume that the default compiler is included with the install of code::blocks - I downloaded the program only a few days ago and chose the one that comes with mingGW compiler - but this compiler is not on the list. I suspect my problem might lie here?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when creating my first multi source code project. i believe the problem you are having is not with the linking but with you #include statement for me the directory's were different to what i expected. to include the header file in a project i had to write `#include "include/other.h"` have a look at how your folder system is constructed....if you could post what folders/directory`s you have in the project i might be able to give you a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and found that if I just closed the project, created a new blank console application then imported the existing files things started to compile fine.

Comment: Doesn't this make you feel Code::blocks is a piece of crap?

Answer (score 1):

Ensure all files (.h and .cpp) have been added to the project with Project>Add Files... or Project>Add FIles Recursively...

Comment: For what it's worth, this is the Code::Blocks solution.

Comment: @theJollySin wow I wrote this answer when I was a noob and still used Code::Blocks instead of a Makefile like a normal person.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, you transfer complete programs to the console application as instructed but then you still get an error message. What worked for me: the core scripts shared between the programs should be rewritten (backspace, and select them from the menu that appears when you type in the first few characters), it's almost as if its to manually point out and call Code::block's attention to their shared kinship. LOL.