# OpenCV undefined reference to my own method in library

Tags: c++, c, oop, opencv, object

I wrote a piece of software in C++ OpenCV, that's so structured:

- main.cpp
- testfps.cpp
- testfps.hpp

The problem is that I get the these two errors

> undefined reference to "myTestfps1(int, int)"
>   undefined reference to "myTestfps2(int, int)"

These two method are written in **testfps.cpp** and declared in **testfps.hpp**.

In **main.cpp** are declared all the necessary `#include <name>`, and after them there is `#include "testfps.hpp"`

---

## **main.cpp**

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <iostream>

    #include "testfps.hpp"

int main(int argc, char** argv[]){
    ....
    switch(c){
    case 1: myTestfps1(a,b);break;
    case 2: myTestfps2(a,b);break;
    }
...
}
```

## **testfps.cpp**

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "testfps.hpp"

int myTestfps1(int a, int b){
...
}
int myTestfps2(int a, int b){
...
}
```

## **testfps.hpp**

```
#ifndef TESTFPS_HPP
#define TESTFPS_HPP

int myTestfps1(int a, int b);
int myTestfps2(int a, int b);

#endif
```

What's wrong with this?

Comment: Did you really add testfps.cpp to your project?

Comment: I created a project on code::blocks, I just build that, bt I don't know if the compile ignore testfps.cpp how could I check?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main issue you might be having, as Samuel pointed out, is that you're not including testfps.cpp in your compilation.

If you're running on linux with g++, try this:

```
g++ -o testfps main.cpp testfps.cpp
```

In any case, since you're working on C++ I recommend you don't use C headers such as stdio.h and stdlib.h. Instead use cstdio and cstdlib:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
```

Finally, your definition of main is wrong, argv is not a pointer<sup>3</sup>:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
```

or:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
```

Comment: OK, good! But now I get errors 'undefined reference to openCV methods'. Should I link libraries in CLI after g++ -o testfps main.cpp testfps.cpp ?

Comment: Thank you I solved using also this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971206/codeblocks-how-to-compile-multiple-file-projects