# Undefined reference to global array

Tags: c++, arrays, global-variables

I have an array called `vel` declared inside `global.h` and defined inside `global.cpp`. When I try to use it inside a function, `get_velocities()`, of another class called `Robot` (inside `Robot.cpp`), it says:

> undefined reference to `vel'

Here are the three files:
1) `global.h`

```
#ifndef GLOBAL_H_INCLUDED
#define GLOBAL_H_INCLUDED
#include <array>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::array;

static constexpr const int marker_num = 10;
static constexpr const int dim = (2 * marker_num) + 3;
extern array <float, 3> vel;

#endif // GLOBAL_H_INCLUDED
```

2) `global.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cmath>
#include "global.h"
#include "WorldState.h"
#include "Robot.h"
#include "Sensor.h"
#include "Marker.h"

array <float, 3> vel = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0};
```

3) `Robot.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cmath>
#include "global.h"
#include "WorldState.h"
#include "Robot.h"
#include "Sensor.h"
#include "Marker.h"


Robot::Robot(float a, float b, float c){

    //ctor
    x = a;
    y = b;
    theta = c;
}

void Robot::get_velocities(){

    v_tx = 1.0;
    v_ty = 0.0;
    omega_t = 0.0;

    vel = {v_tx, v_ty, omega_t};

}
```

**Edit:**

I did read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix) . What I realized was that the global variable requires not just a declaration but also a definition. I have provided this definition inside `global.cpp`. Also when I include `#include "global.cpp"` in `Robot.cpp`, it works (But this is not an acceptable practice). So, I believe this error is due to global.cpp not linking properly.

1) Isn't it a common practice to declare global variables in `global.h` and keep the definitions in `global.cpp`? How do I link them properly? I believe that one way is to create a proper `make` file. However, I am using `codeblocks IDE`. How do I do it in this IDE?

2) Is it better to eliminate `global.cpp` and do all definitions for global variables and functions inside the `main` or the file that uses them?

Comment: Is there any compiling warninga if you compile with `-W -Wall` flags?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: I tried enabling `-Wall`. I received no additional messages.

Comment: Why so many includes in `global.cpp` if it just contains a single variable?

Comment: I though I might need them as I proceed.

Comment: @SyamprasadKR: That's bad coding style. You should include only what you need.

Comment: @Christian Hackl: Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was that the `Codeblocks IDE` was not linking `global.cpp`. I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971206/codeblocks-how-to-compile-multiple-file-projects) (first answer). I apologize if this question is a duplicate or combination of duplicates.

Comment: Codeblocks IDE neither compiles nor links anything. It is a graphical interface which invokes the real tools.

Comment: I apologize for such mistakes. I am still learning. I guess the proper thing to say was that the setting of the IDE didn't invoke the tools to link required file.

Comment: I have observed that IDEs often hide or obfuscate what's really happening; they keep beginners from understanding the fundamental basics of the build process. I would advise all beginners to start with a very simple text editor like Notepad+  and use the command-line tools.

Answer (score 0):

Declare and define the array `vel` within `global.h`. Maybe storing them within the same class would help.

Comment: I am including `global.h` in many places. It will throw `multiple definition error`.