# Class won't work with .hpp file included in main, but does with .cpp file include in main

Tags: c++, class

I'm having an issue with classes in that my IDE tells me that I have an undefined reference to my constructor if I include my .hpp file in main, but not if I include my .cpp file in main instead.  My problem is that in class and across various sites, it should be the .h or .hpp file included in the main. Here are my files:

*Student.hpp*

```
#ifndef STUDENT_HPP
#define STUDENT_HPP

class Student
{
private:
    std::string lastName;
    double gpa;

public:
    Student();
    Student(std::string LastName, double Gpa);

    void setLastName(std::string LastName);
    std::string getLastName();

    void setGpa(double Gpa);
    double getGpa();
};

#endif //STUDENT_HPP
```

*Student.cpp*

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Student.hpp"
using namespace std;


Student::Student()
{
    lastName = "unknown";
    gpa = 0.0;
}
Student::Student(string LastName, double Gpa)
{
    lastName = LastName;
    gpa = Gpa;
}

void Student::setLastName(string LastName)
{
    lastName = LastName;
}

string Student::getLastName()
{
    return lastName;
}

void Student::setGpa(double Gpa)
{
     gpa = Gpa;
}

double Student::getGpa()
{
    return gpa;
}
```

*main.cpp*

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Student.hpp"

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    Student liz = Student();
    cout << liz.getLastName() << endl;



    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Edit: This doesn't appear to be a duplicate to me, I don't even have the ability at this point to really understand the linked page. If it somehow says the same thing, it's in another language to me and I still needed the help.

Comment: Whatever you are doing, it is only compiling **main.cpp**; you need to compile **Student.cpp** as well and link them together.

Comment: Definitely not a duplicate of that. I have compiled Student.cpp; can you be more specific about how to "link them together"?

Comment: @ULTIMATEDEMISE2 How are you compiling your code?

Comment: @ULTIMATEDEMISE2 _"Definitely not a duplicate of that"_ It definitely is. _"because look at them both."_ Just including the headers isn't enough finally.

Comment: @user0042 maybe you could explain how they're the same, to the untrained eye (mine)...there are zero similarities.

Comment: @melpomene Through codeblocks. I'm essentially new to coding; is the gist of what I'm being told that this method really only works through command line?

Comment: @ULTIMATEDEMISE2 No, it just means your project is set up wrong.

Comment: I don't like omnibus answers like What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?, but it does cover this problem [in answer number 3.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12574400/4581301)

Comment: Ohhhh, does this method only work in a "Project"? I haven't ever used that option, or been told to...yikes.

Answer (score 4):

You should compile Student.cpp and main.cpp together.
e.g in linux

```
g++ main.cpp Student.cpp -o a.out
```

You will get only one output named "a.out" that links all of them together. Then run the a.out.

For windows codeblocks:

[code::blocks - how to compile multiple file projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971206/codeblocks-how-to-compile-multiple-file-projects)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oXaC8t-gPVY

Comment: Make sure to #include <Student.hpp> in main.cpp too.

Comment: I guess what he is trying to express with Student.hpp is #include "notesClass.hpp".

Comment: Sorry, I renamed them something that made sense for this but yes. Thanks, @ssovukluk, I'll try that!

Comment: Its okay. Try solutions carefully. It will work on windows and linux