# Undefined reference to Class::Class/Function (Beginner in OOP)

Tags: c++, function, class, object, undefined

I have this annoying error;
Undefined Reference to Shape::Shape(...), Shape::getName(...), Shape::getAge(...)

My Main.cpp is this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Bit.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //simple assignment
    string name;
    int age;
    cout<<"enter name: ";
    cin>>name;
    cout<<"enter age: ";
    cin>>age;

    Shape sh(name,age); //class declaration (i think here is the problem)

    cout<<endl<<"name: "<<sh.getName();
    cout<<endl<<"age: "<<sh.getAge();




    return 0;
}
```

This is the Bit.h header

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

#ifndef BIT_H
#define BIT_H

 //creating class
class Shape{
    string newName;
    int newAge;

public:
    //Default Constructor
    Shape();
    //Overload Constructor
    Shape(string n,int a);
    //Destructor
    ~Shape();
    //Accessor Functions
    string getName();
    int getAge();

};
```

And finally, this is the Bit.cpp

```
#include "Bit.h"
//constructors and destructor
Shape::Shape(){
    newName="";
    newAge=0;
}

Shape::Shape(string n, int a){
    newName=name;
    newAge=age;
}

Shape::~Shape(){

}

string Shape::getName(){
    return newName;
}
//getters
int Shape::getAge(){
    return newAge;
}
```

I understand, that this might be a very simple problem/error, but I have been struggling for about 2 hours.
I suppose that the error is in the declaration od "sh" object, even if I declare it like this "Shape sh();" or "Shape sh;", there are still errors.
Thanks

EDIT. GNU GCC Compiler
EDIT2. Using Code Blocks (sorry for forgetting all these)

Comment: How do you compile this?

Comment: Sorry that I didn't add this above. GNU GCC Compiler and build target is main.cpp

Comment: You need to compile and link every cpp file, not just `main.cpp`

Comment: There are tons of typos or mistakes in the files.  (Looks like some have since been fixed.)  Once I fixed those, it compiled and ran correctly for me.

Comment: Your compiler is not the interested part here. **What** and **how** you are compiling are.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: @UnholySheep do I think I linked the other two as well, isn't the include "Bit.h" enough (for main.cpp and bit.cpp)?

Comment: "linked" != `#include`d

Comment: No, including a header is not enough to tell the compiler that it needs to compile another source file and link it. e.g.: a precompiled library provides a header file and no .cpp file - a compiler simply doesn't know that you expect it to compile and link another file

Comment: Also, what is "OJ"?

Comment: @underscore_d , I don't actually know what it actually means (what and how). OJ is also a typo, i wanted to type OO(Object Oriented).

Comment: @UnholySheep , I don't understand well, I am in such a low level and I have some trouble keeping up with you. Your help is much appreciated, however.

Comment: @Eljay , I was quite sure about that, can you point some of them for me? I have already changed some

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably not compiling `Bit.cpp`, but only `Main.cpp`.

Considering that `Bit.h`, `Bit.cpp` and `Main.cpp` are in the same folder, here is how you should compile it :

```
g++ *.cpp
```

It will still not compile, as in the default constructor, you're trying to initialize `name`, and `age` which both don't exist.

You probably meant `newAge`, and `newName`?

In the other Constructor, `name` and `age` also don't exist, you probably meant `n`, and `a`?

Comment: That was a typo, indeed, still the same errors appear

Comment: Can you show us the exact compilation line you use then? Because it works for me.

Comment: you mean this? ||=== Build: Debug in 12345 (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
obj\Debug\main.o||In function `main':|
C:main.cpp|16|undefined reference to `Shape::Shape(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int)'|
C:main.cpp|18|undefined reference to `Shape::getName[abi:cxx11]()'|
C:\main.cpp|19|undefined reference to `Shape::getAge()'|
C:\main.cpp|16|undefined reference to `Shape::~Shape()'|
C:\main.cpp|16|undefined reference to `Shape::~Shape()'|

Comment: I suppose it is not typed correctly, still have some trouble typing here

Comment: I mean like the one I told you to try : g++ *.cpp -I./.
Are you using Visual studios? Or are you compiling in a terminal?

Comment: Did you put bit.cpp and main in the same folder? Did you change working directory to the folder containing the source code before you type the compilation command?

Comment: Yes, I have. Everything is in the same folder, no changes in working directory

Comment: It means CodeBlocks is only compiling your main. You must change CodeBlocks compiling command to compile Main.cpp and Bit.cpp

Comment: See this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971206/codeblocks-how-to-compile-multiple-source-files

Comment: I think everything is fine with that, the previous project (a big one) worked, I think I have some errors in code, not compiler but you know better

Comment: Actually, whitout the typo errors and with the right compilation command, it works fine. So it has to be a compilation command issue.

Comment: `-I./` is redundant

Comment: Yes,  I was wrong, I actually hadn't checked the boxes for the "Bit.h" and "Bit.cpp". Feels bad. Thanks for the help!

Comment: How do I close it?

Comment: You just did by selecting my answer as the solution

Comment: Oh, I see ^^. Thanks again :D