# Why is the CodeBlocks compiler not recognizing a function that I declared in a header file in C?

Tags: c, function, codeblocks, header-files

I recently looked into defining functions using a header file in C. 
I followed a tutorial online, but I have come across an issue:
If I use command prompt and run the executable file I created in my project folder, it takes the input from my main.c file and passes it through the function like I expected it to.

The command that I typed in Command Prompt was:
`gcc matrix_product.c main.c`

Within main I can call the function (which I named matrix_product), and it recognizes it. When I try to build it inside CodeBlocks, however, the compiler indicates 2 errors:

`undefined reference to 'matrix_product'`

`error: ld returned 1 exit status`

This is the code:

> > main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "matrix_product.h"
#define N 3

int main()
{
    int i,j;
    int m[N][N]={
                {1,2,3},
                {4,5,6},
                {7,8,9}
                };

    matrix_product(m,3);

    for(i=0;i<N;i++){ 
        if(i==1){printf("M^2 = ");
        }else{printf("      ");}

    for(j=0;j<N;j++){
         printf("%d ",m[i][j]);
    }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

> > matrix_product.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "matrix_product.h"

void matrix_product(int m[][3],int DIM)
{
    int i,j,k;
    int tmp[DIM][DIM];

     for(i=0;i<DIM;i++){
        for(j=0;j<DIM;j++){
            tmp[i][j]=m[i][j];
            m[i][j]=0;
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<DIM;i++){
        for(j=0;j<DIM;j++){
            for(k=0;k<DIM;k++){
                m[i][j]+=tmp[i][k]*tmp[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> > matrix_product.h

```
#ifndef MATPROD
#define MATPROD

void matrix_product(int m[][3],int DIM);

#endif // MATPROD
```

Comment: Please indicate the exact command line parameters passed to the compiler. The compiler and linker need to be provided with a *definition* for `matrix_product`, not just a declaration, and to do this, the compiler must be passed a command line that includes `matrix_product.c` (or it must be compiled to a library and linked at a later step)

Comment: It's not a problem with the code. It's a problem with the way you have set up your project. Probably you have not included `matrix_product.c` in your project.

Comment: @kaylum how can I include it?

Comment: A good place to start would be the [codeblocks manual](http://www.codeblocks.org/docs/manual_codeblocks_en.pdf). It tells you in detail how to add files to your project.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I wrote it like that in the actual code, that was a misprint on my part when I copied to the website, sorry.

Comment: @anastaciu I haven't defined it, I was trying to pass a value corresponding to the dimension of the matrix as a parameter to the matrix_product function. Where should I define it?

Comment: @TI84ES, yes sorry, read diagonally.

Comment: `main()` is not a valid signature for anything but a default constructor in a class called `main`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Ok, sorry man, I'm not a programmer, I'm just trying to learn some things for my college's computer science class.

Comment: @TedLyngmo That's what I typed, and it produces the executable file which works. But I'm not being able to build it in CodeBlocks 17.12

Comment: @TI84ES everything is fine with the code, you could include stdio.h and stdlib only in the header file but those are details, something in code blocks config is not right, or you didn't set up the project correctly, I found this 9 year old thread, though it's C++, the problem looks similar, see if it helps https://stackoverflow.com/q/5971206/6865932

Comment: @anastaciu Thank you! but Ted Lyngmo already figured it out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`main.c` seems to be the only source file added to the project in `CodeBlocks`. Add the source file `matrix_product.c` to the project by using `Project->Add files` and it'll compile that too and link (`ld`) with the object file it produces.

Just having the file in the same folder does not make CodeBlocks understand that it should include the file in the project.

Comment: More on setting up the project can be found here: http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/Creating_a_new_project

Comment: @TI84ES Great! Varsågod! :-)